# mocked JSONObject cannot retrieve value that was added

Tags: java, json

I think there's something wrong when I'm trying to spy `JSONObject` using `Mockito`. Here's code from unit test method:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("token","value");

JSONObject spyJson = Mockito.spy(JSONObject.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(JSONObject.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(spyJson);
service.getToken(json.toString());
```

Here's the beggining of the method `getToken()`:

```
public LoginResponseData getToken(String response) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject resJson = new JSONObject(response); //resJson = {} here

    //do stuff

    }
```

In my build.gradle I've added:
`testCompile 'org.json:json:20140107'`

Comment: Works fine for me, too, `org.json:json:20160212`

Comment: Also, you probably want to `spy` `json`, not `JSONObject.class`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you have written is just fine. Make sure the library(**java-json.jar**) jar you are using is the correct one.

I've re written the same code of yours in my custom created Class **JSONTest** bellow and it works fine.

I've downloaded the java-jason.jar form [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java-json/java-json.jar.zip) which has the same package as mentioned by you in the comment "**org.json.JSONObject**"  (you can try using the linked jar into your project).

Below is the working code snippet:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

    public class JSONTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("key", "value");
            String jsonString = json.toString();

            String key = new JSONObject(jsonString).getString("key");
            System.out.println(key);

        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
value
```

Comment: This is not the situation I've described, I'll add the answer in a moment,

Comment: You changed the question just after I answered

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was here:

```
JSONObject spyJson = Mockito.spy(JSONObject.class);
```

As @Sotirios Delimanolis have mentioned, I should spy on `json`, not the `JSONObject` class. Here, I was always getting the default `{}` value, no matter what, because `spyJson` was a new spy of `JSONObject` class and it had no knowledge of previously added `token` key. After changing it to:

```
JSONObject spyJson = Mockito.spy(json);
```

It works as expected.